# Netsuite Formula - "blank" or "null" field

Tags: case, formula, netsuite

I'm trying to use a formula to get a field populated with the word "false" in NetSuite, but currently when I use this I get nothing showing up. If I modify it slightly to say "null" or "blank" or leave it as just a space, it returns an error.

The code I'm using is

```
CASE WHEN {custitem_upc_number} = 'null' THEN 'FALSE' END
```

Answer (score 16):

Try

```
CASE WHEN {custitem_upc_number} is NULL THEN 'FALSE' END
```

Also, for NetSuite Null check related formulas - give NVL and NVL2 a try

Syntax :

NVL({expression1}, {expression2})

NVL2({expression1}, {expression2}, {expression3})

Comment: @user2793912 can you give some more details about the thing that you are trying

Comment: I can identify blanks in some fields with `=''` (equals two single quotes) but others fail with that method.  `IS NULL` did the trick for me!